# R package moments installation

Tags: r, package

I installed in my RStudio the moments 0.14.1 package from the CRAN repository and it shows as installed.

But when I try to run a simple test I get an error:

```
> library(moments)
> 
> # Generate some test data
> x <- rlnorm(100,meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1)
> library(moments)
> 
> # Generate some test data
> x <- rlnorm(100,meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1)
> 
> # Calculate the logmean of the test data
> mean_x <- meanlog(x)
Error in meanlog(x) : could not find function "meanlog"
```

I am using R version 4.2.1. I don't know how to fix it, so I'm asking for help

Comment: are you sure that `logmean` isa function of `moments`? the documentation doesn't list it https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/moments/moments.pdf

Comment: I'm correcting it now.

Comment: I still have a error. In the subsection mean_x <- meanlog(x) should I use another function to calculate the mean?

Comment: I suppose what I'm trying to say is that R can't find the function as the function doesn't exist in `moments`, it exists as a parameter for rlnorm, but not as a function on its own

Comment: if you type `moments::` in RStudio you should see all the functions related to moments in a drop down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, you generated data that were log normally distributed in `x` by specifying the parameters `meanlog` and `sdlog` in the `rlnorm` function. This doesn't have anything to do with `library(moments)`.

Since the lognormal distribution is nonlinear, you must do some transformation to get the arithmetic mean and variance/standard deviation of `x`. You can write your own function:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rlnorm(100, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1)

meanlog_fun <- function(y) {
  ests <- MASS::fitdistr(y, "lognormal")[[1]]
  mn <- exp(ests[1] + (ests[2] ^ 2) / 2)
  sd <- exp(ests[1] + (ests[2] ^ 2) / 2) * sqrt(exp(ests[2] ^ 2) - 1)
  c(mean = mn, sd = sd)
}

meanlog_fun(x)
# mean.meanlog   sd.meanlog 
#     1.653437     1.871858
```

Since this is a coding forum I wont get into the math, but the formulas for the transformation can be found almost anywhere, see [the wikipedia page on the lognormal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution).